# SmartGWT: hide current element showing in Canvas

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm working something like a dynamic menu, where you click some radio buttons and it shows a specific form, each radio control matches to a different form.

Examples from the showcase always base themselves on the Tabs widget and I don't need that behaviour.

I opted for placing all the forms inside one Canvas and hide/show them accordingly (Not sure this was the best idea, if someone knows better I would like to hear it)

Now my problem is that every onClick event has to .show() one form and .hide() the other 9. that is annoying.

Is there a way to "get" the current displayed child in the Canvas and hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is basically mutex display, you could put all the components as members of a Layout instead of a Canvas, then use setVisibleMember().  That hides all other members.

Comment: simple problem, simple solution. thx

PS: how could this work somehow in conjunction with animateFade()?